# Sending unicode command with TIdCmdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe, indy, indy10

I`m using Delphi XE6 and Indy 10

I want to send an Unicode String as Command to a TIdCMDTCPServer from a TIdCMDTCPClient

I`m sending command with SendCMD method of IdCMDTCPClient component but received command shown as ' ? ' Character !

In fact I have a Command (for example : "USER_REG") and some parameters with that and Parameters are an Unicode String ( Persian characters )

I have set encoding of command to IndyTextEncoding_UTF8 or Encode command with UTF8Encode function but there is no chance !

Example of Command :

```
CMD := 'USER_REG#register_user(' + QuotedStr('محمود مهری') + ')';
TCPClient.SendCmd(CMD, -1, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

or

```
TCPClient.SendCmd(UTF8Encode(CMD), -1, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

How can I send Unicode Strings as Command ?

thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdCmdTCPServer` and `TIdCmdTCPClient` are not designed to be used together.  If you are using `TIdCmdTCPServer`, you should be using `TIdTCPClient` instead.  If you want to use `TIdCmdTCPClient`, then at the very least **DO NOT** use its `SendCmd()` or `GetResponse()` methods.  `TIdCmdTCPClient` uses an internal reading thread to receive messages from the server.  That thread will interfere with `GetResponse()`'s reading (`SendCmd()` calls `GetResponse()` internally).  Use the client's `IOHandler.WriteLn()` method instead, and then let the `TIdCmdTCPClient.CommandHandlers` read the server's response.

That being said, specifying `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` on the actual send is the correct thing to do.  You can alternatively set the client's `IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property instead.  Either way, using `UTF8Encode()` in this situation is useless in Delphi 2009+, because `SendCmd()` (and `WriteLn()`) takes a `UnicodeString` as input, so the UTF-8 encoded `RawByteString` that `UTF8Encode()` returns will get converted by the RTL back to a UTF-16 `UnicodeString`, which `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` will then re-encode back to UTF-8 again during transmission.  That is useless overhead.

On the server side, you need to use `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` on the reads so the incoming UTF-8 encoded commands will be decoded correctly.  Since `TIdCmdTCPServer` is doing the actual reading for you, you will have to assign `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` to the `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property in the `OnConnect` event.  Otherwise, Indy's default encoding will be used instead, and that encoding is US-ASCII by default (configurable via the `IdGlobal.GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable).  That is why you are seeing the client's non-ASCII characters being converted to `?` characters.  US-ASCII does not supports characters above `#127`.